# foreach loop displaying below content summary

Tags: plugins

I am trying to wrap my result with `<li>`, but when I do so as in the code, I get funny results, as the result display way below.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
$value = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_package');

foreach ( $value as $values ) {
    echo "<li>";
    echo $values->name;
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Your code will `echo` you list items (without the required `ol` or `ul` wrapper) where ever the woocommerce hook runs. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @s_ha_dum i have lots of modification that i want to do, but i think altering hooks for woocommerce will help me out? Where can i start?

Comment: Please follow up on the questions you asked, it's an important part of the process on WPSE - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) for a deeper insight. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into the action like this:

**Code:**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'wpse124226_wc_product_attribute_list' );
function wpse124226_wc_product_attribute_list() {
    $value = get_the_terms( $product->id, 'pa_package');
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ( $value as $values ) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo $values->name;
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Take a look at the codex [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to inform yourself about using hooks. BTW you can use woocommerce functions to get the attributes, especially `get_attributes`, take a look at the [source at the woocommerce documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Product.html). For an use-case take a look at the [product-attributes.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/release-2-0-20/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php) file.

Comment: +1 to let you reach 2000 rep, you deserve it because you're (almost) the only user here who still answer WooCommerce questions :)

Comment: Haha, thanks, I'm trying to, because despite of the whole controversy I feel many woo question aren't worst then others I answer. And last but not least, the people behind just want a little bit of help, so why not giving it to them, if I can. @G.M.

Comment: For anyone wondering what controversy I'm talking about take a look at [meta].

Comment: @ialocin how do i know, what woocommerce calls its backend variables like u did pa_packages?

Comment: I have gotten `pa_package` from your code, generally woocommerce prefixes products attributes with `pa_`. @Nofel

Comment: @ialocin i got pa_package from someone code, but if i want to get names of what is it called, where can i find it? In DB?

Comment: the naming convention for product attributes is `pa_{$name}` @Nofel

Comment: @ialocin what if its something like 'product category' with space?